# How to improve query speed on Laravel many to many relationship in a filter system?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, query-optimization

I built a website with laravel 8.
The server is a 6 cores CPU / 6 GB Ram VPS. Server is Linux CentOS with nginx and mysql 8.

At peak period, there is about 500 visits online simultaneously. The CPU become 100% during the peak period and >80% in rest of the time.

I checked the usage and found most resource is used by mysql. Then I located some slow queries and I think this many-to-many relationship query is one of the main cause.

There is a Video model and Genre model with many-to-many relationship setup. In the video table, there is about 800,000 rows. There is 700+ genres in genre table and there is 237,4344 relationships in `genre_video` table. `videos.id` and `genres.id` are primary index of `videos` and `genres` table respectively. foreign keys are set up in `genre_video`

**Video model**

```
class Video extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
   public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
    }

}
```

**Genre Model**

```
class Genre extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class);
    }
}
```

Tables

```
videos
id           video_info1           video_info2          type_code
1            somethining           somethining          1
2            somethining           somethining          1
3            somethining           somethining          1

genres
id           genre_name
1            G1
2            G2
3            G3
4            G4
5            G5


genre_video
genre_id         video_id
1                1
1                3
1                5
2                1
2                3


previews (one-to-one with video)
id          image
1           aaa.jpg
2           bbb.jpg
3           ccc.jpg


titles (one-to-one with video)
id          title
1           aaa
2           bbb
3           ccc
```

**Filter function**

I have a genre list on my website. When visitor click on the genre, it changes the url.

For example:
Gerne list: `G1 G2 G3 G4 G5`

when visitor click on G1, the url become `/?c=1`

then visitor click on G3, the url become `/?c=1,3`

then visitor click on G5, the url become `/?c=1,3,5`

The function will get all selected genre id as array `$cArr`. Then I use `whereHas` to loop through the array to find all videos that match genre 1,3,5. As the visitor add more genre in the filter, they could find exactly what they want. i.e. video with id = 1 in the example. But this query took about 20-50s.

```
if($request->c){
                $c = $request->c;
                $cArr = explode(',',$c);
                $data = Video::where('type_code',$type_code)
                            ->whereHas('genres',function ($query) use($cArr) {
                                $query->whereIn('genres.genre_id', $cArr);
                                }, '=', count($cArr))
                            ->join('previews','previews.code','=','videos.code')
                            ->join('titles','titles.code','=','videos.code')
                            ->orderBy('publish_date', 'DESC')
                            ->limit(400)->get();
}
```

- $type_code will only equal to 0,1,2,3
- previews and titles are one-to-one relationship with videos

My question is:

- Is there a way to make this query better but maintain the filter function?
- I have check on the internet people say we should use index engine like `sphinex`. I don't know if it is compatible with my settings `linux + centOS 7 + nginx + mysql 8 + laravel 8`. Any advise on using an index engines?

## Update

Thank you for taking time to read my question. Here are some example of the actual generated queries. The time is already at the best speed as it has the lowest traffic at the time of the day.

The first one is when the visitor clicked on G2 and G13. He will see 400 videos that with genre G2 and G13.

```
select * from `videos` 
inner join `previews` on `previews`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
inner join `titles` on `titles`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
where `type_code` = 0 and (
    select count(*) 
    from `genres` 
    inner join `genre_video` on `genres`.`id` = `genre_video`.`genre_id` 
    where `videos`.`id` = `genre_video`.`video_id` 
    and `genres`.`genre_id` in ('2', '13')
) = 2 order by `publish_date` desc limit 400

Query took 13.58s
```

The second one is when the visitor clicked on G2, G13 and G18. He will see even precisely filtered 400 visdeos with all these genres

```
select * from `videos` 
inner join `previews` on `previews`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
inner join `titles` on `titles`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
where `type_code` = 0 and (
    select count(*) from `genres` 
    inner join `genre_video` on `genres`.`id` = `genre_video`.`genre_id` 
    where `videos`.`id` = `genre_video`.`video_id` 
    and `genres`.`genre_id` in ('2', '13', '18')
) = 3 order by `publish_date` desc limit 400

Query took 14.04s
```

## Update 2

I added the columns ,index and relationship screenshots. I am sorry I cannot provide the laravel migration file as I created these table in phpmyadmin before I learn migration. But seems all required relationship is add according to the many-to-many documentation.

`actors`
[image]

`videos`
[image]

`actor_vidio`
[image]

`previews`
[image]

`titles`
[image]

Sorry again for making the question messy.

## Update 3

```
EXPLAIN select * from `videos` 
inner join `previews` on `previews`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
inner join `titles` on `titles`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
where `type_code` = 0 and (
    select count(*) from `genres` 
    inner join `genre_video` on `genres`.`id` = `genre_video`.`genre_id` 
    where `videos`.`id` = `genre_video`.`video_id` 
    and `genres`.`genre_id` in ('2', '13', '18')
) = 3 order by `publish_date` desc limit 400
```

[image]

```
EXPLAIN select * from `videos` 
inner join `previews` on `previews`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
inner join `titles` on `titles`.`code` = `videos`.`code` 
where `type_code` = 0 and (
    select count(*) from `genres` 
    inner join `genre_video` on `genres`.`id` = `genre_video`.`genre_id` 
    where `videos`.`id` = `genre_video`.`video_id` 
    and `genres`.`genre_id` in ('2', '13', '18')
) = 3 order by `publish_date` desc limit 400
```

[image]

## Update 4

I added `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

`actors`

```
actors
CREATE TABLE `actors` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `actor_id` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs NOT NULL,
 `actor_type` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `actor_img` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `actor_sex` int DEFAULT '2',
 `actor_cn` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `actor_tw` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `actor_en` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `actor_ja` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `actor_ko` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `actor_id` (`actor_id`),
 KEY `actor_sex` (`actor_sex`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=89588 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`videos`

```
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `type_code` int NOT NULL,
 `code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `publish_date` date NOT NULL,
 `duration` int NOT NULL,
 `download` int NOT NULL,
 `sub` int NOT NULL,
 `online` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `leak` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `javdb_url_code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_single_actor` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
 KEY `type_code` (`type_code`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `code_fulltext` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=458527 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`actor_video`

```
CREATE TABLE `actor_video` (
 `video_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `actor_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`,`actor_id`),
 KEY `actor_video_actor_id_foreign` (`actor_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `actor_video_video_id_foreign` (`video_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `actor_id` (`actor_id`),
 KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `actress_video_actress_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`) REFERENCES `actors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `actress_video_video_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `videos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`previews`

```
CREATE TABLE `previews` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `video_preview` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `image_pl` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `image_ps` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `image_preview_s` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `image_preview` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=458096 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`titles`

```
CREATE TABLE `titles` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `code` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `title_cn` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `title_tw` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `title_en` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `title_ja` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `title_ko` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `code` (`code`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `title_index` (`title_ja`,`title_en`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */ ,
 CONSTRAINT `title_video_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES `videos` (`code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=458101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`genres`

```
CREATE TABLE `genres` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `genre_id` int NOT NULL,
 `genre_type` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `genre_cn` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `genre_tw` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `genre_en` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `genre_ja` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `genre_ko` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `type_code` int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `genre_id` (`genre_id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `genre_cn` (`genre_cn`,`genre_tw`,`genre_en`,`genre_ja`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1536 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`genre_video`

```
CREATE TABLE `genre_video` (
 `genre_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `video_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 KEY `genre_video_genre_id_foreign` (`genre_id`),
 KEY `genre_video_video_id_foreign` (`video_id`),
 KEY `genre_id` (`genre_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `genre_video_genre_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genres` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `genre_video_video_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `videos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please let me know if I have to add more information. Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: One solution would be indexing of mysql table columns where you search.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I have already indexed all the columns in the where clause, including `type_code`, `genre_id`, `id` in genres, `id` in videos, and also those keys for one to one foreign keys.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table. Your query pattern (`SELECT a_mess_of_stuff... ORDER BY something LIMIT 400`) is difficult to optimize without refactoring the query a bit.  sphinxsearch.org will definitely work on your server, but I'm pretty sure you don't need it.

Comment: And, by the way, your server is provisioned just fine. Throwing more hardware at this problem won't help you.

Comment: Thank you for you time! I have added 2 actually generated queries. Please have a look when you have time. @O. Jones

Comment: Thanks for showing the query to us lavavel-illiterates. Table definitions? `SHOW CREATE TABLE` ?  Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info).

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you for your reply. I have added SHOW CREATE TABLE in Update 4. I don't know if it make it clearer, I added some screenshots

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for your reply. I have added EXPLAIN SECLECT in Update 3. Please have a look.

Comment: @Philip - Update 3 is a huge cross-join and a useless Explain. I hope that is not a query that is used in production.  Please do `EXPLAIN` for the queries in the original "UPDATE".

Comment: @Philip - `SHOW CREATE TABLE genre_video` is also critical.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, I miss the genres tables and misunderstood the EXPLAIN. Now I updated the 2 EXPLAIN in original query in `Update3` and updated the SHOW CREATE in `Update 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many:to:many tables tend to be poorly indexed, leading to lots of extra CPU.  This shows the optimal schema (no auto_inc) and indexing (2 composite indexes):

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: I have removed the auto increment of row id. There are only video_id and genre_id column left in the table. The values are unsigned and not NULL. The primary index is now (video_id,genre_id). I have also make the single column index. Unfortunately, the query still tooks about 20-30 seconds. Is there another way to do this query? Or should I use some indexing tool that could integrate laravel 8 and mySQL 8? Thank you for your time to read my long question!

Comment: @RickJames, you're gonna get the old "link-only answer" smackdown unless you enlarge this excellent suggestion.

Comment: @Philip - I still see `id` in `genre_video`.  Please update the question.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you. I have updated the new `genre_video` which the `id` is removed

Comment: I don't see any PK now.

Answer (score 0):

First, your common key for your JOINs is `code`.

It's defined like this in  `titles`

```
code varchar(50)
```

and like this in `videos` and `previews`

```
code varchar(255)
```

That's not good for performance in `ON` conditions. Define all three `code` columns precisely the same.

Next issue: Let's bid adieu to the dependent subquery.

We can write it

```
              select genre_video.video_id
                     from genres
                     join genre_video ON genres.id = genre_video.id
                     join videos on genre_video.video_id = videos.id
                    where genres.genre_id IN (2, 13, 18)
                      and videos.type_code = 0
                 group by genre_video.video_id
                   having COUNT(*) = 3
```

to get the `video_id` values matching the three genres.

Then we JOIN the subquery into another yet subquery. This does the heavy lifting of `order by ... limit 400`.

```
      select code
        from (
                   select genre_video.video_id
                     from genres
                     join genre_video ON genres.id = genre_video.id
                     join videos on genre_video.video_id = videos.id
                    where genres.genre_id IN (2, 13, 18)
                      and videos.type_code = 0
                 group by genre_video.video_id
                   having COUNT(*) = 3
             ) matches
        join videos ON matches.video_id = videos.id
       order by publish_date desc
       limit 400
```

Only then do we join to the various tables and do the `select *`

```js
select *
  from (
          select code
            from (
                  select genre_video.video_id
                         from genres
                         join genre_video ON genres.id = genre_video.id
                         join videos on genre_video.video_id = videos.id
                        where genres.genre_id IN (2, 13, 18)
                          and videos.type_code = 0
                     group by genre_video.video_id
                       having COUNT(*) = 3
                 ) matches
            join videos ON matches.video_id = videos.id
           order by publish_date desc
           limit 400
       ) chosen
  join videos on chosen.code = videos.code
  join titles on chosen.code = titles.code
 order by videos.publish_date;
```

This should help a lot.

Sorry to say, I don't know how to code this in Laravel.

You didn't show us `genres`, But it should have these two indexes for this kind of thing to work efficiently. It doesn't need indexes on either individual column.

```
PRIMARY KEY (video_id, genre_id)
INDEX (genre_id, video_id)
```

(By the way, this advice about indexing applies to `actor_video` too.)

Tricky problems like this are the sign of real application. You should monitor performance as your app grows. You may need other indexes, or need to refactor other queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will run tests with you query provided today. I will reply here once I finished.

Comment: I ran a test today. The query time drop from 10-20s to 2-3s. I decided to remove the genre from the search result. Then I modify you code to be only relationship on `videos` and `genre_video`. The query time is about 1-2s now. Thank you